# Requirement not satisfied while installing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip

I'm trying to install Pandas library for Python. But when I run

```
python -m pip install pandas
```

It gives an error

```
couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.9.3 (from versions:
1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0b1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1,1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0,
1.14.1, 1.14.2)
No matching distribution found for numpy==1.9.3
```

I've already installed the latest version numpy==1.14.2 and I also tried to uninstall it and then reinstalling pandas but it still didn't work. 
I tried to install pandas without dependencies by running

```
python -m pip install pandas --no-deps
```

but it's also not working.
What's going wrong here?

Comment: What is your pip version? Check this issue on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20697). It seems there is a bug with pip later than 10.x and the suggested work around is using version 9.0.3

Comment: As noted in the referenced git issue, you may try `pip install pandas --no-build-isolation`

Comment: @prabhakar It did work but then another error (visual c++ is required) appeared on the screen. So I decided to install an older version of pandas (0.16.0). It's working fine. Thanks for your comment.